# Excluding users who used specific events from a group-by aggregation

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery to find out how many users used specific events on my app. Here is my code to find out

number of users per 3 event combination.

```
-- 3 EVENT COMBO'S

WITH EventUsers AS (

SELECT user_pseudo_id, event_name

FROM `table_name`

WHERE event_name IN ('a','b','c','d','e','f')

AND event_date

BETWEEN

'20231101' AND '20231130'

)


SELECT

e1.event_name AS event1,

e2.event_name AS event2,

e3.event_name AS event3,

COUNT(DISTINCT e1.user_pseudo_id) AS common_users_count

FROM

EventUsers e1

JOIN

EventUsers e2

ON

e1.user_pseudo_id = e2.user_pseudo_id

AND e1.event_name < e2.event_name

JOIN

EventUsers e3

ON

e2.user_pseudo_id = e3.user_pseudo_id

AND e2.event_name < e3.event_name

GROUP BY

event1, event2, event3

ORDER BY

common_users_count DESC;
```

---

The thing I want to change here is that for each combination of events shown in the result set, I want the common_users_count to exclude those users who used any other event listed in the EventUsers CTE at the top, for example let's say the first row of the current result set is as follows:

```
event1     event2       event3          common_users_count
a           b             f                500
```

in this case I want to exclude those users who had the following events ‘d’, ‘e’, and ‘c’

in the time duration shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `NOT EXISTS` to remove the unnecessary users as follows:

```
WITH EVENTUSERS AS (
    SELECT
        USER_PSEUDO_ID,
        EVENT_NAME
      FROM
        TABLE_NAME
     WHERE
        EVENT_NAME IN ( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' )
           AND EVENT_DATE BETWEEN '20231101' AND '20231130'
)
SELECT
    E1.EVENT_NAME                     AS EVENT1,
    E2.EVENT_NAME                     AS EVENT2,
    E3.EVENT_NAME                     AS EVENT3,
    COUNT(DISTINCT E1.USER_PSEUDO_ID) AS COMMON_USERS_COUNT
  FROM
         EVENTUSERS E1
      JOIN EVENTUSERS E2 ON E1.USER_PSEUDO_ID = E2.USER_PSEUDO_ID
       AND E1.EVENT_NAME < E2.EVENT_NAME
      JOIN EVENTUSERS E3 ON E2.USER_PSEUDO_ID = E3.USER_PSEUDO_ID
       AND E2.EVENT_NAME < E3.EVENT_NAME
       ----------------- Use NOT EXISTS as follows:
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            1
          FROM
            EVENTUSERS EE
         WHERE
                EE.USER_PSEUDO_ID = E1.USER_PSEUDO_ID
               AND EE.EVENT_NAME NOT IN ( E1.EVENT_NAME, E2.EVENT_NAME, E3.EVENT_NAME )
    )
 GROUP BY
    EVENT1,
    EVENT2,
    EVENT3
 ORDER BY
    COMMON_USERS_COUNT DESC;
```

Comment: thanks but it says "EXISTS subquery is not supported inside join predicate"

Comment: Updated the answer. It should be in WHERE clause.

Comment: thanks it works, may you have a happy and blessed life!